# Angular Material theming / changing border radius

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, mat-dialog

I am using Angular Material with a theme.

```
$my-theme-redish: (...
$my-theme-red: (...
$my-theme-celeste: (...

$my-theme-primary: mat-palette($my-theme-redish);
$my-theme-accent:  mat-palette($my-theme-celeste);
$my-theme-warn:    mat-palette($my-theme-red);

$my-app-theme: mat-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $my-app-primary,
    accent: $my-app-accent,
    warn: $my-app-warn,
  )
));
```

Now I also want to theme/change the `border-radius`. Can I do this in theming? I did not find any documentation on this.

I tried theming by using `::ng-deep` or directly adressing certain components:

```css
::ng-deep mat-dialog-container {
  border-radius: 20px !important;
}
```

But nothing worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-material-dialog-utxye6?file=src/styles.css) Did you try to add

```
.mat-dialog-container {
  border-radius: 20px !important;
}
```

inside global `styles.css`

or if you just want this dialog then give custom class with `panelClass` options as example below

```
this.dialog.open(dialogComponent, { panelClass: 'custom-container' });
```

and

```
.custom-container .mat-dialog-container {
   border-radius: 20px !important;
}
```

inside global `styles.css`

Comment: Can you check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang-material-dialog-utxye6?file=src/styles.css

Comment: My fault, i used `mat-dialog-container` instead of `.mat-dialog-container`. Thanks for the effort, it now works!

Comment: Component DOM structure and CSS classes are considered private implementation details that may change at any time.

Answer (score 3):

For angular V16 add in your custom-theme.scss or in styles.css

```css
 .mat-mdc-dialog-container {
  --mdc-dialog-container-shape: 20px;
}
```